# PHP Coding Error For Sensei Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Some days ago a have created a website only for videos in wordpress by using UVC plugins, and used many more paid plugins, like sero traffic magnet, bounce control, and than wp sensei. But problem is with wp sensei, installed it successfully, but can't activate it anyways. tried more, says that trigged fatal, in the line of 108 with wp sensei. my website link is [***website design company***](http://www.makeusawebsite.com) . I need this problem solve fast. Thanks.

It's the 108 number line of wp sensei "if($bans[$i]['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])"

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the code block with

```
if(array_key_exists('ip',$bans[$i])){
```

ie:

```
if(array_key_exists('ip',$bans[$i])){
   if($bans[$i]['ip'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
      //plugin code is here
   }
}
```

this will check to see if the array key IP is present within the array listings,